# Any suggestions for PHP/Browser communication with DBus?

Tags: php, dbus

I'm doing some research for a project; we're planning on using dbus on the system side and I'm trying to get the dbus messages out into a browser for JS to handle.

I've been looking at PHP Ratchet with PHP's out dated dbus pecl extension, but I've been wondering if someone has some magical answer for this.

Maybe having PHP make a GET request to a dbus daemon and have the daemon hang the connection until a message is received?

Comment: The closest I've gotten to anything working is using the dbus pecl extension for PHP to connect and read dbus messages.

The issue with PHP is its single threaded, blocking nature. But I have to use PHP as part of the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. Exposing a internal IPC mechanism out all the way to JS to handle individual messages, sounds like a intresting concept.

My initial thinking would be to have a cron job query the bus at set intervals and then have the results fed into a SQL database, This would also give you the freedom to separate the user account which is doing the IPC away from the apache webserver account. as well as giving you the ability to use a library with a little bit more support (such as the perl or python dbus bindings. )

then have php query the DB ( and remove any messages which have been processes ) and finally have Javascript spin and query the PHP for updates...

This way you don't have any 'blocking' io, as well as having a little bit more separation between the web server and dbus.

Comment: Hrm... I may be able to use the file system to store the messages. This is an embedded device environment. Sadly no databases. But that's essentially the path I'm leaning towards too. Two separate processes. One to grab the dbus messages and one to send them out HTTP.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Kind of an important bit of information. ;)